# Size of datasets over years

Tags: dataset, statistics, bigdata, search

I am looking for statistics, to understand the evolution of the size of the (public) dataset over the years.

I just found the following statistics:

- The poll of [KDnuggets](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/10/poll-results-largest-dataset-analyzed.html) that actually shows that over the years is the following:

> Gigabytes still rule: Majority of answers (56% in 2018, 57% in 2016, 56% in 2015, 54% in 2014, 53% in 2013) are in Gigabyte range. The overall median response was again between 11 and 100 GB (which comfortably fits on one laptop) for each year since 2012.

Do you know where to find better statistics?

I guess that the **average** size of the dataset has increased.
If not, I would like to see if at least the size of company-data available has increased.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at the article you quote of [KDNuggets](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/10/poll-results-largest-dataset-analyzed.html), in this article they analyze the data from this last year (poll), but they have been doing that for several past years.

Perhaps by looking at past years you can extract some better data.

Also in this other forum https://opendata.stackexchange.com/
they talk about open data, maybe here you can get a more precise answer

[image: KDD Nuggets Data history]